# Destroy static mutex and rwlock initializers

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

Let's suppose we have a global mutex or rwlock initialized with a static initializer:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

or

```
pthread_rwlock_t lock = PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;
```

Documentation says it's equivalent to `pthread_*_init` with default parameters.

Do we have to destroy a mutex or rwlock initialized this way?

Answer (score 8):

No. The difference between a statically allocated and a dynamically allocated mutex is basically comparable to a variable located on the stack or in the heap. You don't have to give a mutex back that you didn't allocate dynamically. 
Quoting from Michael Kerrisk's "The Linux Programming Interface":

> When an automatically or dynamically allocated mutex is no longer required, it should be destroyed using pthread_mutex_destroy(). (It is not necessary to call pthread_mutex_destroy() on a mutex that was statically initialized using
>   PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER.)