# Can a static initializer macro require dynamic cleanup? (could pthread_mutex_initializer ever require pthread_mutex_destroy?)

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I have viewed many other questions regarding this topic and I feel that I am informed on the topic... But there is one aspect to the question that I want to discuss.

As stated here [Destroy static mutex and rwlock initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295021/destroy-static-mutex-and-rwlock-initializers/42155550#42155550)

> (It is not necessary to call pthread_mutex_destroy() on a mutex that was statically initialized using PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER.)

However I want to pose a more fundamental question:

If an API provides a macro to initialize an object/type, similar to the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`, then is there anything that macro could expand out to which would REQUIRE a call to a dynamic destructor function?

To clarify what I'm asking:

Is there anything that could be done in the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` that would require a dynamic destructor to cleanup?

Would it be okay to safely assume that if an object/type has a static macro initializer like `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` that it is **impossible** for the macro to initialize anything that would need dynamic cleanup, and therefore it's impossible for `pthread_mutex_destroy` to ever be necessary for `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`?

Or is it possible to change something in the future that may cause `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` to do some operation that would absolutely require the `pthread_mutex_destroy` function to be called?

edit: The only thing I could think of would be to maybe register a gcc `__attribute__((constructor))` or something in order to automatically call some code, at which point it's not really a static initialization anymore right? If it was truly a static initialization then that *by definition* means it cannot do anything dynamic; ergo *by definition* a static initializer macro couldn't require a dynamic cleanup function, right?

Comment: It could allocate resources dynamically on first use. In case of failure, it can fall back to polling. For example `CRITICAL_SECTION` can allocate internal event dynamically when it is requires. In theory an implementation can free such event in destroy function.

Comment: Good point I never considered the first-use scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If an API provides a macro to initialize an object/type, similar to
>   the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`, then is there anything that macro could
>   expand out to which would REQUIRE a call to a dynamic destructor
>   function?

In general, yes.  A macro can expand to a function call, or to an initializer containing one, which might return a pointer to dynamically allocated space or a structure or union containing such a pointer.

But for `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` or any other macro that can be used to initialize a file-scope variable, no.  Such initializers must be constructed from constant expressions, and there is nothing such an initializer could contain that would obligate cleanup.

Do note, however, that that's not a complete story.  However an object is initialized, there are innumerable ways in which its subsequent use could cause a requirement for releasing resources via a destructor function to adhere to it.  In particular, [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html) does not promise that failing to destroy a mutex initialized via the macro will be without consequences.  Nor does it draw any distinction between the initial state of a mutex initialized via the initializer macro and the initial state of one initialized via `pthread_mutex_init()` with default attributes.  Either way, resources requiring cleanup could be associated with such a mutex by calls to `pthread_mutex_lock()`, for instance.

But don't overlook that any "requirement" in this realm is conditional, not absolute.  Calling `pthread_mutex_destroy()` is potentially required *in order to* achieve a desirable outcome, such as avoiding a resource leak.  Not making the call means obtaining a different outcome, which may still be an acceptable one.

Perhaps a good example would be the `NULL` macro.  Any pointer object may be initialized with `NULL`, which does not have any resource-management implications.  If a pointer to dynamically-allocated space is subsequently assigned to it, however, then failing to ever pass that object's value to `free()` may cause a resource leak.  Yet such a leak may be acceptable -- for example, if the allocated space needs to be retained until program termination anyway, then it makes little practical difference whether the program releases it itself, or whether it relies on the OS to handle that as part of cleaning up after the process.

Answer (score 2):

That quote is specific to Linux, and is a consequence of the fact that on linux, pthread_mutex_destroy is essentially a noop.  From the manual page:

> pthread_mutex_destroy  destroys  a  mutex object, freeing the resources it might hold. The
>          mutex must be unlocked on entrance. In the LinuxThreads implementation, no  resources  are
>          associated  with  mutex  objects,  thus pthread_mutex_destroy actually does nothing except
>          checking that the mutex is unlocked.

Thus on Linux, pthread_mutex_destroy is never required, for any mutex.

Comment: Note that the LinuxThreads implementation is completely obsolete and hasn't been supported since glibc 2.3 (although roughly the same is true of the NPTL implementation - `pthread_mutex_destroy()` just checks that a robust mutex is unlocked, and sets the mutex to an invalid value).